# How to test an API using Mockito?

Tags: flutter, dart, mockito

I am trying to learn unit testing in general and Mockito in particular. When I see simple examples of cats meowing, it makes sense to me. But now I want to test at least one class from my real-life projects. And I don't understand what to do.

For example, I have the following class:

```dart
class NewsApi {
  final Dio dio;
  final String apiKey;
  final String query;
  NewsApi({required this.dio, required this.apiKey, required this.query});
  Future<List<NewsEntity>> getRecentNews() async {
    final res = await dio
        .get('/v2/everything?q=$query&sortBy=publishedAt&apiKey=$apiKey');
    return List<Map<String, dynamic>>.from(res.data['articles'])
        .map((e) => NewsEntity.fromJson(e))
        .toList();
  }
}
```

In the test folder I created a file news_api_test.dart. But what and how to test? The only thing I could write was:

```dart
class MockDio extends Mock implements Dio {}

void main() {
  late Dio dio;
  late String apiKey;
  late String query;

  late NewsApi newsApi;
}
```

But what next? Please provide example code testing my class.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you want to mock Dio, you should look into https://pub.dev/packages/http_mock_adapter